# Using d3js within objects - this context collision

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, d3.js

I want to use d3js within an object (Backbone.View in my case).

The problem I am facing (being both a javascript and a d3js newbie) is that in functions on selections the "this" context is set to the current Dom object. So I cant access the object methods anymore within the function. If I bind the function to the "this" of the object (via underscore for example) I loose access to the current Dom object. In case of events I found some workaround using d3.event yet I hope to get some general advice how to use d3js within objects and solving the described problem in general. (without workarounds...)

Thanks

martin

UPDATE:

As an example, within the "selection.each(function)" ([see d3js API docu](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#control)) the this is the current DOM element so I cant access methods of the object (this.objectMethod())

Comment: Can you save `this` in a variable in the corresponding context and then access it elsewhere, e.g. `var that = this;`?

Comment: can you show some code to make it clear ?

Comment: Thanks Lars for the suggestion. The problem is that I cant access the that variable either as I would need this.that to access it from within the function - as far as i see it

Comment: For example " selection.each(function) " within this function the this is the current DOM element so I cant access methods of my object, this.myObjectMethod()

Comment: You can reference `this.that` as `that` from within the function as long as you do not have another `var that` in the function, http://jsfiddle.net/6H5Qf/.

Comment: doesn't the backbone view have an "el" property to store it's DOM element? Would that provide the access you need?

Comment: Thanks Brant, I understand now that my problem boils down to a lack of javascript knowledge ...

Comment: Thanks Superboggly. Right now I hold all elements within one view (with el being the svg DOM element) as the handling of the DOM elements is done anyway by D3 - not sure if this makes sense so ...